# xgb.DMatrix hangs in mclapply

Tags: r, linux, xgboost, mclapply

I've encountered this already raised issue:
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2094

We've moved our parallel solution to mclapply, but have had issues when running xgb.DMatrix this way. the process hangs when it hits this function, but works ok sequentially.

The data sets within our loops are independent of one another. The poster has some sample code that hangs in a linux machine.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what we could try? I didn't find the response in the github issue to be helpful.

Comment: Following the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2094) to the [GCC Bug Report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58378) and finally [OpenMP HowTo | OpenMP and fork()](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#OpenmpAndFork): *"There is currently no workaround; the libgomp API does not specify functions that can be used to prepare for a call to fork()"*.

Comment: However, Jakub Jelinek has this to say about the proposed patch in the [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58378#c3): *"There is no point trying to hack around bugs in your code inside of libgomp, simply follow the requirements how you can use fork in multithreaded apps"*.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's a shame as the in-built multi-thread is less useful in our case. We have the pre-trained parameters and the models are quick to run over the data segmentations. However there are a lot of them, hence we use mclapply to try to speed it up. It doesn't look as valuable to use multi-threading within xgboost, due to the overhead at that level.